# How to run existing SWF file on Adobe Air

Tags: flash, air, adobe, flex3

I have an application that uses adobe flex, MXML and ActionScripts and currently, it runs in the browser. So all the files are bundles in SWF and browser has flash player that runs this SWF file.

Since flash is sunsetting so we have to migrate it to other technology with minimum effort. I found out that we can use Adobe Air (maintained by HARMAN) with minimal changes. I want to know how SWF file can be run on Adobe Air on Mac?